# Is there an easier way to clear a Google sheet using script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

I am trying to find a better way to clear filters on 12 different sheets of Google versus what I have put in. This clearing function takes the longest amount of time of my script to run.

An example of what is complete and works is below. Each sheet has 46 columns that I need to clear, and there are 12 sheets. This seems a little excessive but this is the only way that I've found that will do this, and it is a necessary step otherwise the other script won't run. Any way to improve on this? It's the same row on every sheet, exact same info, just different things could be filtered.

```
var IT = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ktIHQMhr8RcoHJishstT4xDtO2PnU26MzDAW0Fe1Cks').getSheetByName('IT');

IT.getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(1);
IT.getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(2);
IT.getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(3);
IT.getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(4);
IT.getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(5);
IT.getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(6);
IT.getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(7);
IT.getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(8);
IT.getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(9);
IT.getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(10);
IT.getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(11);
IT.getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(12);
IT.getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(13);
IT.getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(14);
IT.getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(15);
IT.getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(16);
```

Comment: `sheet.clear()`[doc reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#clear) - "Clears the sheet of content and formatting information."

Comment: I've looked through these and it doesn't produce the outcome that I want. I just want to clear all the filters out, not contents or color or anything. I don't see a line that's that specific though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your code is fine, it just need some optimizations here goes some:

```
function clearFilters(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // or SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ktIHQMhr8RcoHJishstT4xDtO2PnU26MzDAW0Fe1Cks').getSheetByName('IT')
  var headers = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var filter = ss.getFilter();

  for(var i=1,len=headers.length;i<=len;i++){
    filter.removeColumnFilterCriteria(i);
  }
}
```